# Convert HTML form Post Param string to Java Map

Tags: java, spring-mvc, post, converters, apache-commons

I am reading the request body payload from an HttpServletRequest instance. the body is created by HTML form post. e.g. "param1=value1&param2=value2&param1=value3", thus it will have string and array as the value of the param. And I want to convert it into Map so that the Object can be either String or List

Is there a utility method I can use from apache-commons, googlecommon/guava, or springframework that can make this magic happen without me checking whether it is an array of values or just a single value etc?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want from the query String? A Map has a key and a value. How do you want each of those? Give us an example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, the map will be "param_name"=>collection of "param_values", be the values either list or array. I eventually have to write a quite generic function and use reflection to work through the case for several cases. Didn't find anything within the mentioned frameworks that can achieve my goal. Hope this helps